# Could for possibility

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, infinitives

Do we say : 
 - we could go **to** see the match on Sunday.
                  Or
 - We could go **and** see the match on Sunday.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You could say either, as the meanings are equivalent.

Comment: Both are fine. 

This sometimes gets picked up, but I think it’s an erroneous generalisation of the problem with “try and”.

Comment: Googel Ngrams for the search terms **go to see,go and see** indicates that **go and see** has been consistently more popular.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+to+see%2Cgo+and+see&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20and%20see%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20and%20see%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

I would leave out both words in my speech, and probably in my writing.

Aside from my colloquial preference, I believe it's "to". You're not going to the place and also seeing a game. You're going to the place to see the game. If you use "and", it's unclear. With “and”, you could be saying that you'll have time to see the game after you get home from an outing